How many maximal length snakes are there?
This problem was motivated by the classic phone game Snake.
Consider the square grid graph with vertex set $V := \{1, \dots, N\}^2$, for fixed odd positive integer $N$, and an edge between $(x, y)$ and $(x’, y’)$ iff $|x - x’| + |y - y’| = 1$.
Question: How many paths are there from $(1, 1)$ to $(N, N)$ that do not repeat any vertex but traverse all vertices? Can we get, if not exact results, asymptotics in $N$?

Maybe https://doi.org/10.1016/0012-365X(95)00330-Y is one paper to start looking at. There is no hope of an exact solution here. Even precise asymptotics are not so easy, I think, and ought to be related to deep questions in statistical mechanics

Yes I expect an exact solution to be more or less impossible haha @SamHopkins

By a simple parity argument there are none for even $N$, so if you want to talk asymptotics you need to restrict to odd $N$.

@PeterTaylor Yes that makes sense..

OEIS A001184 doesn't have much other than a few small terms. The cross-referenced sequence A121788 has a couple of links to an archived website by I. Jensen, but the archive is timing out on the page "Series Expansions for Self-Avoiding Walks", and "Crossing Hamiltonian walks" just lists the terms. The name of the non-loading page suggests that it might be similar in content to the paper Sam Hopkins linked above.
